# Why am I not able to suggest edits for Meta.movies posts?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits

I am not able to **suggest edit** on the posts in Meta.movies. I can see the `edit` button, but it is greyed. Other buttons are working fine. What is the reason?

Edit: I can edit my own posts on meta.

Comment: Are we talking grayed out to the point where it is unclickable?

Comment: it is unclickable!

Comment: This is by design.  I've added the relevent information to ian's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from the [Meta FAQ,](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you need 1000 reputation to edit someone's post.  You cannot **suggest edits** on a site's meta.

[image]

Comment: It is unclickable!